# Put a lot selector in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a client that want to put all background-color and color in script
like this instead using CSS files:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".blog-navi a:hover:before,.filter > a.active,.flex-direction-nav .flex-next:hover,.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev:hover").css({"background-color":"green","color":"white","padding":"10px"});
});
```

And honestly, I have like 70 class selector. What do you think about how long it will take to load the page?

Comment: As you tagged css, I will suggest you to use css only. Put all those classes and styles in a stylesheet. If you **can't** do this, please specify in your post, because is the best way to do it.

Comment: You cannot select pseudo elements like `:after`,`:before` so you cannot set css styles for them from javascript like that. You would have to create a new [CSSRule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSRule) and add it to a [CSSStyleSheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet), or creating a new `<style>` element and set the css rules in the `textContent`

Comment: i know i cant use :pseoudp but what if i put 50 different class in selector (lets say its a normal class like .demo1 a,demo1 p,demo2 a,demo2 p until 80 times) on there. is that make load page slow?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown honestly its for change color theme, i already set multiple color.css for him to choose and to active it just to add class at body. for example if i wanna make blue just like this <body class="blue">. but my client want to using via script